# ReactJS TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code right here, that works in this online text editor: **https://codesandbox.io/s/o4n0v203vy**

In the **npm console**, everything is okay:

[image]

But in the **browser**, this happens:

[image]

What logs in the console, when i do `export var renderTree = (node, setActiveNode, activeNode) => { console.log(node && node.type, 'look here');`

[image]

I can't figure out why is this happening. Any help is appreciated! 
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the same dummy data?

Comment: @Colin what do you mean?

Comment: You have dummy data in the Codesandbox. Are you using dummy data locally too? If not, please post that data here.

Comment: @Colin ah yes, i'm using the same dummy data.

Comment: Try to console the node type `export var renderTree = (node, setActiveNode, activeNode) => {
  console.log(node && node.type, 'look here');` Do you see node type?

Comment: @Liam: `directory look here
              3file_tree.js:187 directory look here
              5file_tree.js:187 file look here
              5file_tree.js:187 file look here
              file_tree.js:187 undefined "look here"`

Comment: @Liam: This is what is logging in the console. The last item logs "undefined look here"

Comment: Well, check last item if everything is correctly because the last item caused this error

Comment: Does your code is exactly the same on codesandbox?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169595/discussion-between-timmy-and-liam).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `node` is `undefined` so doesn't have a property called `type`.

Change your check to

```
if(node && node.type === 'file'){
    ...
}
```

Comment: after applying your solution the error is gone, but the file tree doesn't appear in the browser, which is weird.
@Stretch0

Answer (score 2):

You're probably running the source file in your browser instead of the built one.